# Using super within nested class

Tags: python, inheritance

I am puzzled with the following error in python 2.7.12
Suppose we have a class definition within a class, something similar to this:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "class C"


class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "class D"


class A(D):

    class B(C):
        def __init__(self):
            # Strangely here B is "not defined", why?
            super(B, self).__init__()
            print "class B"

    def __init__(self):
        super(D, self).__init__()
        print "class A"

    def do_something(self):
        b_class = self.B()
        print "b_class within A : {}".format(b_class)


a_class = A()
a_class.do_something()
```

but if we we extract the definition of class `B` outside the scope of class `A`,
everything works well.

Do we need to use "super" differently when called within a nested class? I fail to understand why its usage would be different within or outside the nested class. Any pointers?

Comment: *Any pointers?* There are no pointers in Python ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not the subclass or superclass, but the nesting. `B` itself is not defined, only `A.B` is.

Note that in Python there is almost never a good reason to nest classes, though.

Comment: Indeed that is the case, although I would have thought that super implicitly took the context into account...

Answer (score 4):

You need to address `B` by its full name, `A.B`:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "class C"


class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "class D"


class A(D):

    class B(C):
        def __init__(self):
            super(A.B, self).__init__()
            print "class B"

    def __init__(self):
        super(D, self).__init__()
        print "class A"

    def do_something(self):
        b_class = self.B()
        print "b_class within A : {}".format(b_class)


>>> a_class = A()
>>> a_class.do_something()

class A
class C
class B
b_class within A : <__main__.B object at 0x7f0cac98cbd0>
```

Comment: @Leon that's because `A.__init__` calls `super(D, self).__init__()`, which means "calls the `__init__` of D superclass" (in this case `object.__init__`). If you want to invoke `D.__init__` from `A.__init__`, you have to use `super(A, self).__init__()`  instead ;)